# Can't get user information into Serilog plain text log

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext, serilog

I'm trying to implement some simple logging into an application. I am using Serilog, but due to circumstances out of my control, I can't use Seq as the sink. For now, I've been told to simply write the logs to a local file.

I am able to successfully log basic information, but am having trouble with getting the user's information into the logs. `Serilog.Enrichers.Environments` package gets the information just fine, but the methods only enrich the logs, which aren't seen in a plain text log. When I use Seq as the sink (which I can't use for my final implementation) I can see the enrichments being logged just fine.

Currently I am trying to get the user info from the `HttpContext` but it is returning `null`. Here is an example of code that I've tried:

```
public static class HTMLHelperExtensions
{
    public static string CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
            if (httpContext == null || httpContext.User == null)
                return null;

            return httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logging configuration in my `Global.asax`:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
            .WriteTo.File(
                "fileLocation.txt",
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information,
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Infinite,
                fileSizeLimitBytes: 10485760, //10MiB
                retainedFileCountLimit: 50 )                
            .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
            .CreateLogger();
```

And where I'm calling the code from:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        Log.Information("Application initial load. Included in Audit Log: {auditLog}. User: {User}", true, HTMLHelperExtensions.CurrentUser);
        //other code

        return View();
    }
}
```

The `.Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()` method works just fine, but I don't know how to get that information into the actual body of the log instead of an enrichment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're looking for, but you can build a custom enricher with:

```
class CurrentUserEnricher : Serilog.Core.ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(Serilog.Events.LogEvent logEvent, Serilog.Core.ILogEventPropertyFactory lepf) =>
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(lepf.CreateProperty("CurrentUser", HTMLHelperExtensions.CurrentUser));
}
```

And include in pipeline with a:

```
.Enrich.With<CurrentUserEnricher>()
```

Then as long as `{Properties}` or `{CurrentUser}` is in your render format, you'll get the value included ?

Comment: The enricher seems to work, but my problem is that I need it in the main body of the log. I have to send the logs to a plain text file, and enrichments don't show up there. I'm hoping to find a way to make enrichments carry over to the main log, if that makes sense

Comment: You can add [`{Properties}` to the format string for the main log](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output) - this will include all fields from enrichers etc. that are not used in the rest of the message

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out for now. If I use `httpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` instead of `httpContext.User.Identity.Name` it gives me the information I want.

If there is a way to use the Serilog configuration to append this info to the log body instead of how I'm doing it, I will accept that answer.